# How to pass a Fragment as a callback to DialogFragment using Navigation Architecture Component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have a ParentFragment that implements a callback Interface.
From that fragment I call a DialogFragment (using childFrgamentManger) and passing ParentFragment as a parameter. Pressing a button on DialogFragment calls a ParentFragment's method that updates the ParentFragment.

Now, I am trying to implement that using Navigation Architecture and I can't figure out how to pass the ParentFragment as a parameter to DialogFragment.
Most examples I saw pass either Strings or Integers.

Comment: Passing fragment instance in dialog is not good way, though you can pass it by creating setter in dialog fragment and pass the instance of the parent in that dialog fragment.